# Image of Union is Equal Union of Images

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, solution-verification

I would hope someone can help me verify my solution for this seemingly basic set theory problem. We are given that $f : X\longrightarrow Y$ such that $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq X$ and are asked to show:
$$
f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)
$$
I have proved it this way :
\begin{align*}
y\in f(A\cup B)&\iff\exists x\in A\cup B\;;\;y=f(x) \\
&\iff (x\in A)\lor(x\in B) \\
&\iff[f(x)\in f(A)]\lor[f(x)\in f(B)] \\
&\iff f(x)\in(f(A)\cup f(B)) 
\end{align*}
Is this proof correct? Also I wish to ask what is the difference between in these two notations for a function of a set :
$$
f(X)\qquad\text{and}\qquad f[X]
$$
and if they have same meaning which one is the better to use?

Comment: The symbol $f$ seems to be absent from the second line in your chain of equivalences. What did you mean there? Also, the symbols $f(X)$ and $f[X]$ mean the same. Sometimes (this is very frequent in set theory), we have a function $f:X\to Y$ and some set $A\subset X$ which is also an element of $X$, i.e. $A\in X$ (for example, $\{\{0\},\{\{0\}\}\}$. Then the symbol $f(X)$ becomes ambiguous, do we mean the image of the subset $A$, or the value of the function $f$ at the point $A$? To distinguish between these, square brackets are sometimes used.

Comment: Hello, I fixed this mistake. I understood your point. This makes much more sense now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is much too sloppy to be correct.
y in f(A $\cup$ B)
iff
exists x in A $\cup$ B with y = f(x)
iff
exists x with ((x in A or x in B)
and y = f(x))
iff
exists x in A with y = f(x)
or exists x in B with y = f(x)
iff
y in f(A) or y in f(B)
iff
y in f(A) $\cup$ f(B)